# No shadow under windows

Tags: windows-7, visual-effects

i am currently running a windows 7 ultimate on my pc.
Yesterday i upgraded my Bitdefender 2014 to 2015 version, and after that i found that there is no shadow showing under my windows(border) or anything. I don't know if it is a Bitdefender bug or anything else!

i also checked if my `visual effect` setting has anything to do with it or not, but there `show shadow under windows` is not checked, and also other options are unchecked and set to custom!! i guess it's bitdefender's doing since it has profile, which disabled them!

well i re-enabled and guess what no shadow still!

here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful. Boot Windows without Bitdefender to prove its Bitdefender disabling this effect.  Update your question once you do this.

Comment: screenshot added, i actually uninstalled bitdefender to see if it was the case but the problem remains even after uninstalling!!

Comment: Your current setting is allowing Windows to enable/disable those features, while there is a checkbox that is selected, Windows will ignore those unless you select `Custom`

Comment: if i select `custom` some of the options get unchecked and if if i rechecked them and save nothing happens, and when i open the `adjust visual effect` box again it reset again.

Comment: Verify all display drivers are Windows 7 certified and are current.

Comment: @Ramhound, well all my drivers are verified, but not updated.

Comment: Come back once you have updated your display drivers and the problem still exists.

Comment: i have updated my drivers and no result, i think some program set my `show windows shadow` settings to uncheck!

here is a image of what i meant:
http://i61.tinypic.com/2d1qr9j.jpg

i think bitdefender may be behind it, as the new bitdefender has a option for that, and it may have done something, even after uninstalling i can't get the shadow back:

http://i62.tinypic.com/2cqio9i.jpg

Comment: hi! is there any way to force enable the shadow option!?? it gets unchecked at every time i save it and re-open

Comment: WHat do you mean Bitdefender has an option for it?  Post a screenshot of said interface and option.

Comment: see the fourth option of the `movie profile`:

[image link](http://i62.tinypic.com/2cqio9i.jpg)

i am not sure if it is BD or not! but my pc was working perfectly until i installed BD 2015!, and even after uninstalling it seems to have no effect, maybe it modified some system files or so. disabling the feature has no effect!

Comment: and why the heck, even i select `show shadow under windows` in `custom` and save, it resets those field!! is there any way to force check them!

Comment: Lol, why did i get a negative vote!! i tried everything from updating to registry hack, and this problem still there!! Did i miss any rules for this Q&A site!!??

Answer (score -1):

I too have the same issue... I installed bitdefender internet security 2015, n it changed to battery mod as my tab battery lowered n the issue said above about windows shadow started. so I disabled the bit defender battery mod n enabled shadows for windows n mouse, but nothing happened, so I removed bit defender n scanned my disk on bootup, also complete system scan n rebooted to check the issue... but the issue still remains...